# What does it mean to "refresh" an ObservableCollection, as stated in the documentation?

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection

The documentation for the [ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) states:

> "Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire
>   list is **refreshed**."

([ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) says the same thing.)

What does it mean by "refresh"?

There is no "`Refresh()`" method on ObservableCollection nor anything that sounds like it would do this. The word "refresh" isn't used anywhere else in the documentation for this class that I can find.

Likewise, its base class `Collection` also has nothing.

At first I was imagining a method which would manually raise an `INotifyCollectionChanged` event, or something like that, to be used in cases where you didn't actually add/remove from the collection. But there is no obvious way to do that.

Likewise, even [the reference source code for this class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs) only mentions "refresh" in the comment header, and nowhere else.

Is the documentation just incorrect? Or am I missing some subtlety about how you would "refresh" an `ObservableCollection` object?

Comment: It may mean anything else than "added, removed, changed, moved", e.g. an atomic replacement of all elements by a collection of other elements - which is not supported by ObservableCollection, but might be by other INotifyCollectionChanged implementations. See also [NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this block of code works for you.

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
        public void Refresh()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.Count(); i++)
                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> ;
{
        public void Refresh();
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.Count(); i++)
                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
}
```